# custom calculation returns 'NoneType' object is not callable django

Tags: django

I'm trying to do some calculation for my system, I need to get all location count for a `superuser` like so

`location = LocationData.objects.filter(email=self.request.user.email).count()`,

then I need to count all licences for that user, like so

`count = MyUser.objects.filter(location_count=self.request.user.email).count()`,

and I need to check if the `location` == `count` and to `*` location with some price,

```
if count == location:
       context['social'] = location * FRISTPRICE
```

when I get the price I need to display it on a template.

The complete view is

```
class AdminDashboard(TemplateView):
    """
    """
    template_name = 'administration/admin.html'

    @cached_property
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AdminDashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)

    # check if user is superuser if not don't include him
        if user.is_superuser:
            # check how much locations does user have
            location = LocationData.objects.filter(email=self.request.user.email).count()

            # check how much user have licences payed for
            count = MyUser.objects.filter(location_count=self.request.user.email).count()

            # if count is == to location then the location is proper
            # so count * package = application sales
            if count == location:
                context['first_package'] = location * FIRSTPRICE

            if count == location:
                context['second_package'] = location * SECONDPRICE

            if count == location:
                context['third_package'] = location * THIRDPRICE

            return context
```

and the full error is [HERE](http://dpaste.com/0YSGGZ1), my first guess is that context can not be returned and that this calculation is not good, so can someone please help me understand why I'm I getting this error, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_context_data` return nothing if user is not superuser. Unindent return context line to fix it:

```
@cached_property
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AdminDashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)

# check if user is superuser if not don't include him
    if user.is_superuser:
        # check how much locations does user have
        location = LocationData.objects.filter(email=self.request.user.email).count()

        # check how much user have licences payed for
        count = MyUser.objects.filter(location_count=self.request.user.email).count()

        # if count is == to location then the location is proper
        # so count * package = application sales
        if count == location:
            context['first_package'] = location * FIRSTPRICE

        if count == location:
            context['second_package'] = location * SECONDPRICE

        if count == location:
            context['third_package'] = location * THIRDPRICE

    return context
```

Comment: Oh, really, facepalm